# Dynamically generated wordpress customizer options?

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I looked for a while, but I couldn't really find anything about this.

So I'm trying to generate a customizer panel with a single option and setting attached, initially. This options is something like number of entries or number of pictures. If the user had already saved certain options in this field, let's call it options_count or something, then I want it to load and generate an options_count number of subgroups.

So for example, say I made a theme that had a slideshow with an uncertain number of images. I code it so that, initially, there are no images whatsoever and the slideshow does not show up. But then, the user enters that he wants three images in the slideshow as the options_count. I want the customizer to recognize that change and generate three sets of options and settings for the user.

Is this even possible? If it is, please help me come up with a solution.

Comment: Definitely, it can be done, but it can be quite a hassle to code the php and javascript for several fields as you intend. Is using a library a solution for you? If that's the case, you can have a look at [Kirki](https://github.com/aristath/kirki), which adds several fields to the WP Customizer. In your case, the [repeater field](https://kirki.org/docs/controls/repeater.html) seems feasible.